# How to fix ClassNotFoundException "com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"

Tags: android

Currently I've got an error which is very hard to find the reason behind. Did someone encountered such an issue? Appreciate any help in that matter.

I don't have facebook library dependency. Although maybe it's added through other libraries as Firebase Auth?

All the libraries used in *build.gradle* file.

```
 implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.18.3'
androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.7.22'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'

implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
```

The exception stack trace.

```
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.CustomTabActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.application-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.application-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2320)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2479)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5420)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: This error occurs when any of the dependency java class in not found.
Here in yours `com.facebook.CustomTabActivity` is used somewhere. It would be good if you share your gradle file.

Comment: Done, my guess is on *com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth*, but I would like to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by java.lang.**ClassNotFoundException**: Didn't find class
>   "`com.facebook.CustomTabActivity`" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.application-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.application-1/lib/x86,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]    at
>   dalvik.system.**BaseDexClassLoader**.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)

I'm suspecting about using `multidex` which you have added the dependency and I assume it is enabled.

**Solution:** Disabling or removing :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

Might help since it sounds like error is coming from `Multidex`. However, that's pretty strange because [CustomTabActivity](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook-common/src/main/java/com/facebook/CustomTabActivity.java) seems to be coming from Facebook SDK and you don't have Facebook dependencies nor using it.

Comment: I will try to use an APK whiteout multidex, although multidex is not necessary from Lollipop, and our current application is using minSdk = 16. Thank you for your response.